# Unexpected keyword-else

Tags: ruby

I have a method which returns finds out which one of the given numbers differs from the others in evenness and returns the index of it (+1).

```
def iq_test(numbers)
  new_array = numbers.split(" ").collect {|n| n.to_i}
  x = new_array.select(&:even?)
    y = new_array.select(&:odd?)

  if x.count > y.count
    new_array.split.each_with_index do |value, index| 
      "#{index + 1}".to_i if value % 3 != 0
  else  y.count > x.count
      "#{index + 1}".to_i if value % 2 == 0
    end
  end
end
```

For example `iq_test("2 4 7 8 10")` should return `3`.

However, I am receiving

> syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end

and I can't find out where I am not closing some code off.

Comment: The `new_array.split.each_with_index do |value, index|` block is not closed.

Comment: It seems like the line containing the if should be located within the do block, instead of before, and the else block should not contain a condition.

Comment: Ah, you were right. However, it only returned an array [2,4,7,8,10] instead of 3.

Comment: There are a lot of things that make no sense in your code: (1) You are opening the block but are not closing it (2) You are suplying a condition to the `else` keyword. Do you mean `elsif`? (3) `new_array` does not response to split. You probably men to use it as is. (4) You are not fetching / generating / returning anything in your loop. Do you mean to use `map`? Or do you want to return in the loop? (5) `"#{index + 1}".to_i` is uselessly complicated. Use `index+1` instead. In general, you probably want to go over the introduction about the very basics of the Ruby programming language again.

Answer (score 5):

This is going to be part code review as well as answer. Let's start with the first part:

```
  new_array = numbers.split(" ").collect {|n| n.to_i}
  x = new_array.select(&:even?)
    y = new_array.select(&:odd?)
```

- Spend time to think of good variable names. I wouldn't use "new_array" as a variable name, because it doesn't provide any clue as to what it contains. Do this kind of thing too many times, and a program becomes incomprehensible.
- `x` and `y` are really `evens` and `odds`, aren't they? Those would be better variable names.
- A common Ruby idiom is to use plural names for arrays, singular names for everything else.
- The `split` by default splits on whitespace, so the `(" ")` is unnecessary.
- Be careful with indentation.
- Your selects are fine, however there is a shortcut: Enumerable's `partition`.
- This is really my own style, but I use `map` when processing all values in an array, and `collect` only when doing something like extracting attributes from an array of objects. (In other words, I use `map` much more often).
- note that `(&:to_i)` is a bit of a shortcut for `{|n| n.to_i}`

Rewritten considering the above, this part might look like this:

```
numbers = input.split.map(&:to_i)
evens, odds = numbers.partition(&:even?)
```

Now let's look at the rest:

```
if x.count > y.count
    new_array.split.each_with_index do |value, index| 
      "#{index + 1}".to_i if value % 3 != 0
  else  y.count > x.count
      "#{index + 1}".to_i if value % 2 == 0
    end
  end
```

And let's consider the error message you got: unexpected keyword `else`; expected `end`. This has everything you need to know to answer the question (and you'll find that most error messages do, if you think about them). It says it found an `else` where it expected an `end`. And that's exactly the problem, you need to put `end` before the `else` to close the do/end block. Also, your `else` part is missing your iteration logic.

Other notes:

- Again, be careful with indentation. Your `end`s do not line up with what they're ending. Proper alignment can help catch these kinds of errors. Use of an IDE like Rubymine or a sophisticated text editor with Ruby support can help as well.
- `else` clauses are standalone, you don't put a condition after them. Perhaps you meant `elsif` as Holger commented.
- Using string interpolation (`"#{}"`) converts expressions to a string. Here you're converting `index + 1` to a string, and then back to an integer with `.to_i` which cancels it out, so to speak. Simply `index + 1` will do.
- `Array#index` can be used to determine the index of a value.
- It's not clear if you want all indices in case there is more than one.

Here's a version considering the above:

```
if evens.count > odds.count
  odds.map{|n| numbers.index(n) + 1}
elsif odds.count > evens.count
  evens.map{|n| numbers.index(n) + 1}
end
```

If you like this kind of thing, bring your working code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/!

Answer (score 1):

This specific error is because you do not have a closing `end` for your `each_with_index` block.  To fix this error you need:

```
def iq_test(numbers)
  new_array = numbers.split(" ").collect {|n| n.to_i}
  x = new_array.select(&:even?)
    y = new_array.select(&:odd?)

  if x.count > y.count
    new_array.split.each_with_index do |value, index| 
      "#{index + 1}".to_i if value % 3 != 0
    end #end of block
  elsif  y.count > x.count #in order for this to have a condition, it must be an elsif
      "#{index + 1}".to_i if value % 2 == 0
  end #end of if statement 
  #end - remove this extra end 
end #end of function
```

Comment: Not exactly. (**Hint:** What are `index` and `value` in the context of the `elsif` block)

Comment: @engineersmnky I was just trying to help him get past the syntax error

Comment: While it will not throw a syntax error anymore. You have simply created a new error (`NameError `)

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def odd_one_out(str)
  evens, odds = str.split.partition { |s| s.to_i.even? }
  case [evens.size <=> 1, odds.size <=> 1]
  when [0, 1] then evens.first
  when [1, 0] then odds.first
  else nil
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
odd_one_out "0 3 4 6"  #=> "3"
odd_one_out "1 5 7 8"  #=> "8"
odd_one_out "0 2 4 6"  #=> nil
odd_one_out "1 5 7 9"  #=> nil
odd_one_out "0 2 3 5"  #=> nil
odd_one_out "3"        #=> nil
odd_one_out "8"        #=> nil
odd_one_out ""         #=> nil
```

**Explanation**

See [Integer#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E).

Suppose

```
str = "0 3 4 6"
```

then

```
a = str.split
  #=> ["0", "3", "4", "6"]
evens, odds = a.partition { |s| s.to_i.even? }
  #=> [["0", "4", "6"], ["3"]]
evens
  #=> ["0", "4", "6"]
odds
  #=> ["3"]
b = [evens.size <=> 1, odds.size <=> 1]
  #=> [1, 0]
b == [0, 1]
  #=> false
b == [1, 0]
  #=> true
c = odds.first
  #=> "3"
```

The `case` statement, and therefore the method, returns `"3"`.